# How to use SSL in TcpClient class

Tags: c#, .net, email, tcpclient

In the .NET framework there is a class `TcpClient` to retrieve emails from an email server. The `TcpClient` class has 4 constructors to connect with the server which take at most two parameters. It works fine with those servers which does not use SSL. But gmail or many other email providers use SSL for IMAP.

I can connect with gmail server but can not authenticate with email_id and password.

My code for authenticate user is

```
public void AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
{
    _imapSw.WriteLine("$ LOGIN " + username + " " + password);
    //_imapSw is a object of StreamWriter class
    _imapSw.Flush();
    Response();
}
```

But this code can not login.

So how can I use the `TcpClient` class to retrieve emails when I have to use SSL?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to use the [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) along with the [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) then use the SslStream to read the data rather than the TcpClient.

Something along the lines of:

```
        TcpClient mail = new TcpClient();
        SslStream sslStream;

        mail.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995);
        sslStream = new SslStream(mail.GetStream());

        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop.gmail.com");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = -1;
        do
        {
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
            decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
            messageData.Append(chars);

            if (messageData.ToString().IndexOf("<EOF>") != -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (bytes != 0);

        Console.Write(messageData.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

**EDIT**

The above code will simply connect via SSL to Gmail and output the contents of a test message.  To log in to a gmail account and issue commands you will need to do something along the lines of:

```
        TcpClient mail = new TcpClient();
        SslStream sslStream;
        int bytes = -1;

        mail.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995);
        sslStream = new SslStream(mail.GetStream());

        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop.gmail.com");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        // Read the stream to make sure we are connected
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

        //Send the users login details
        sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("USER USER_EMAIL\r\n"));
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

        //Send the password                        
        sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PASS USER_PASSWORD\r\n"));
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

        // Get the first email 
        sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RETR 1\r\n"));
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
```

Obviously, without all the duplication of code :)

Comment: Thanks, for your answer.But user login is my main problem.

Comment: very very thanks for your answer. I works great. Somewhat it uses pop protocol to access mail. But i want to access email using imap protocol. I have changed the mailserver name and port number as "imap.gmail.com" and "993" but it does not works. How it can be done?

Comment: How does this change if you are being the "Server" rather than the client? I want to receive connections using ssl?

Comment: I have freeze on bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) in second iteration of loop because messageData.ToString() doesn't have <EOF>

Answer (score 3):

To tailor the best response above specifically to the question of IMAP and IMAP authentication, you will need to modify the code slightly to use IMAP commands as follows. For debugging, you can set breakpoints just after strOut is assigned to view the server responses.

```
            pmOffice pmO = new pmOffice();
            pmO.GetpmOffice(3, false);

            TcpClient mail = new TcpClient();
            SslStream sslStream;
            int bytes = -1;

            mail.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 993);
            sslStream = new SslStream(mail.GetStream());

            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("outlook.office365.com");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            // Read the stream to make sure we are connected
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

            //Send the users login details (insert your username & password in the following line
            sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$ LOGIN " + pmO.mailUsername + " " + pmO.mailPassword + "\r\n"));
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            string strOut = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);

            // Get the status of the inbox (# of messages)
            sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$ STATUS INBOX (messages)\r\n"));
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            strOut = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
```

Comment: What's pmOffice?

Comment: pmOffice is a class I created and used to access my mail settings and credentials from a database.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `NetworkStream` provided by `TcpClient` with an [`SslStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx). This will provide the necessary handling of SSL and certificates.

You may have to insert some handler code to perform a certificate validation callback, e.g. through [`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx).