# How to use SSL Authentication?

Tags: asp.net

I have web application and need to Authenticate server by certificate
this code get error "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"  how can resolve problem

```
X509Certificate2 CER = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("MyServer.cer"), "password");// Has to be a private X509cert with key
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 44300);
listener.Start();
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
Console.WriteLine("client accepted");

try
{
    SslStream stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream());
    stream.AuthenticateAsServer(CER, false, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
    Console.WriteLine("server authenticated");
    stream.Close();
    Console.Read();
}
catch (AuthenticationException err)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", err.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8375137/2791540)

Comment: @JohnWu i don't understand please describe

Comment: have you checked if the port is blocked ? `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`